# How to change css when div hits top of page

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I have a div element with a fixed position and an ID of `#topnav`. I have a div below that with an ID of `#container`. When the user scrolls down to the point of having `#container` at the top of the page, I would like to have the opacity of `#topnav` changed to `0.3`—as long as `#container` is at least at the top of the page.

I have found several similar posts on StackExchange, but none of them seemed to work for me.

I would prefer doing this in plain Javascript, but I can use JQuery if need be. Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: It would always be nice to see the HTML code that you are using, plus any JavaScript/JQuery that you have attempted to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize you asked for a JavaScript solution, but I only know how to do it in JQuery (hopefully someone else can use this to come up with a pure JS solution).

**Fiddler:** [JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/njy59/2/)

**JQuery:**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() == 0) {
        $('#topnav').removeClass('faded');
    } else {
        $('#topnav').addClass('faded');
    }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.faded
{
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```